# Hashmap.keySet(), foreach, and remove

Tags: java, iterator, foreach, hashmap

I know that it's typically a big no-no to remove from a list using java's "foreach" and that one should use iterator.remove().  But is it safe to remove() if I'm looping over a HashMap's keySet()?  Like this:

```
for(String key : map.keySet()) {
  Node n = map.get(key).optimize();
  if(n == null) {
   map.remove(key);
  } else {
   map.put(key, n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you see a ConcurrentModificationException? yes, then it isn't going to work.  If you use ConcurrentHashMap, this will work. However, since you are replacing every element in the map  why don't you build a new HashMap and replace the original?

Comment: Well I was looking for expertise regarding the subject and I've often run into problems in the past when code that ran didn't really work right because I didn't understand it.  Regarding building a new map, it seems to me that it would less efficient to create a lot of new objects(Map.Entry's) than the solution below which allows the modification of the existing object.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

EDIT:

I hadn't noticed that you weren't really *adding* to the map - you were just changing the value within the entry. In this case, pstanton's (pre-edit<sup>1</sup>) solution is *nearly* right, but you should call `setValue` on the entry returned by the iterator, rather than calling `map.put`. (It's *possible* that `map.put` will work, but I don't believe it's guaranteed - whereas the docs state that `entry.setValue` *will* work.)

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Node>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); 
     it.hasNext();)
{
    Map.Entry<String, Node> entry = it.next();
    Node n = entry.getValue().optimize();
    if(n == null) 
    {
        it.remove();
    }
    else
    {
        entry.setValue(n);
    }
}
```

(It's a shame that `entry` doesn't have a `remove` method, otherwise you could still use the enhanced for loop syntax, making it somewhat less clunky.)

**Old answer**

(I've left this here for the more general case where you just want to make arbitrary modifications.)

No - you should neither add to the map nor remove from it directly. The set returned by `HashSet.keySet()` is a view onto the keys, not a snapshot.

You *can* remove via the iterator, although that requires that you use the iterator explicitly instead of via an enhanced for loop.

One simple option is to create a new set from the original:

```
for (String key : new HashSet<String>(map.keySet())) {
    ...
}
```

At this point you're fine, because you're not making any changes to the set.

EDIT: Yes, you can definitely remove elements via the key set iterator. From the docs for `HashMap.keySet()`:

> The set supports element removal,
>   which removes the corresponding
>   mapping from the map, via the
>   Iterator.remove, Set.remove,
>   removeAll, retainAll, and clear
>   operations. It does not support the
>   add or addAll operations.

This is even specified within the `Map` interface itself.

---

<sup>1</sup> I decided to edit my answer rather than just commenting on psanton's, as I figured the extra information I'd got for similar-but-distinct situations was sufficiently useful to merit this answer staying.

Comment: If I remove from the keySet using it's iterator, does it also remove it from the map?

Comment: I went ahead and gave you the accepted answer since even if map.put works, I'm sure entry.setValue is more efficient.  Thanks for looking it up!

Comment: "It's a shame that entry doesn't have a remove method" - that would require an extra field on the Entry object pointing back to the Map object.

Comment: @Stephen: That's very true. It's a bit like the fact that String memoizes its hash code - useful in some situations, annoying everywhere else :(

Answer (score 12):

you should use the entry set:

```
for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Node>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{
      Map.Entry<String, Node> entry = it.next();
      Node n = entry.getValue().optimize();
      if(n == null) 
          it.remove();
      else
          entry.setValue(n);
}
```

EDIT fixed code